# Highstock columns overlapping one another even if there is space

Tags: highcharts

Although I know I can use stacked columns and they do function properly, our unstacked columns are overlapping one another, presumably because there is not enough room to present them alongside each other. But there is!

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pm30yuum/). If I remove the area series (price) then I get [this jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/srmquo4s/) which is kind of what I am looking for (but with price series added):

```
new Highcharts.stockChart({"credits":{"href":"","text":""},"chart":{"zoomType":"xy","renderTo":"researchChartComponentChartContainer62082951"},"yAxis":[{"opposite":true,"title":{"text":"Price"},"labels":{"format":"{value}"},"height":"100%"},{"opposite":false,"title":{"text":"Millions"},"labels":{"format":"{value}"},"height":"100%"},{"opposite":false,"title":{"text":"Margin %"},"labels":{"format":"{value}"},"height":"100%"}],"tooltip":{"valueDecimals":2,"shared":false},"xAxis":{"title":{"text":"Time"},"type":"datetime"},"exporting":{"enabled":true},"plotOptions":{"series":{"animation":false,"marker":{"enabled":false,"states":{"hover":{"enabled":true}},"radius":4}}},"legend":{"enabled":true,"floating":false},"scrollbar":{"liveRedraw":false},"title":{"text":""},"rangeSelector":{"selected":12,"inputEnabled":true,"buttons":

    [
{
    type: 'day',
    count: 1,
    text: '1d'
},  {   
    type: 'day',
    count: 5,
    text: '5d'
},  {  
    type: 'month',
    count: 1,
    text: '1m'
}, {
    type: 'month',
    count: 3,
    text: '3m'
}, {
    type: 'month',
    count: 6,
    text: '6m'
}, {
    type: 'ytd',
    text: 'YTD'
}, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 1,
    text: '1y'
}, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 2,
    text: '2y'
}, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 3,
    text: '3y'
}, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 4,
    text: '4y'
}, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 5,
    text: '5y'
}, {
    type: 'year',
    count: 8,
    text: '8y'
}, {
    type: 'all',
    text: 'All'
}]



    },"navigator":{"adaptToUpdatedData":false,"series":{ id: 'navigator' }},"series":[{"name":"Gross Margin","yAxis":2,"index":0,"id":"Gross Margin","type":"line","data":[[1199059200000,51.12],[1230681600000,52.86],[1262217600000,41.57],[1293753600000,56.3],[1325289600000,59.17],[1356912000000,45.46],[1388448000000,48.16],[1419984000000,33.23],[1451520000000,19.9]]},{"name":"Net Margin","yAxis":2,"index":1,"id":"Net Margin","type":"line","data":[[1199059200000,35.71],[1230681600000,35.32],[1262217600000,23.41],[1293753600000,36.71],[1325289600000,37.94],[1356912000000,11.72],[1388448000000,1.25],[1419984000000,1.75],[1451520000000,-47.36]]},{"name":"EBITDA","yAxis":1,"index":2,"id":"EBITDA","type":"column","data":[[1199059200000,16264.0],[1230681600000,19759.0],[1262217600000,10301.0],[1293753600000,24955.0],[1325289600000,34160.0],[1356912000000,13564.0],[1388448000000,19213.0],[1419984000000,11466.0],[1451520000000,-2102.0],[1483142400000,10539.0]],"pointWidth":10},{"name":"Common Net Inc","yAxis":1,"index":3,"id":"Common Net Inc","type":"column","data":[[1199059200000,11825.0],[1230681600000,13218.0],[1262217600000,5456.0],[1293753600000,17264.0],[1325289600000,22795.0],[1356912000000,5454.0],[1388448000000,584.0],[1419984000000,657.0],[1451520000000,-12129.0],[1483142400000,3982.0]],"pointWidth":10},{"name":"CFO","yAxis":1,"index":4,"id":"CFO","type":"column","data":[[1199059200000,11012.0],[1230681600000,17114.0],[1262217600000,7136.0],[1293753600000,19183.0],[1325289600000,23458.0],[1356912000000,16135.0],[1388448000000,14792.0],[1419984000000,12807.0],[1451520000000,4491.0],[1483142400000,6581.0]],"pointWidth":10},{"name":"Simple FCF","yAxis":1,"index":5,"id":"Simple FCF","type":"column","data":[[1199059200000,4361.0],[1230681600000,8142.0],[1262217600000,-960.0],[1293753600000,6536.0],[1325289600000,7596.0],[1356912000000,813.0],[1388448000000,1687.0],[1419984000000,994.0],[1451520000000,-3880.0],[1483142400000,1630.0]],"pointWidth":10},{"name":"Revenues","yAxis":1,"index":6,"id":"Revenues","type":"column","data":[[1199059200000,33115.0],[1230681600000,37426.0],[1262217600000,23311.0],[1293753600000,47029.0],[1325289600000,60075.0],[1356912000000,46553.0],[1388448000000,46767.0],[1419984000000,37539.0],[1451520000000,25609.0],[1483142400000,27488.0]],"pointWidth":10}]})
```

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to help if you provide a clean version of your code that is readable and usable.  Looks to me like it's a matter of the `pointRange`. You are trying to show several columns in a very tight range x axis values, and that is not going to work the same as a categorized column chart. Basically you're trying to force two paradigms of showing data together - very tight sequential data points in your line series, with broad, grouped, categorized columns. May need to look at breaking into separate x axes.

Comment: You have hardcoded pointWidth - remove it and the columns will not overlap - http://jsfiddle.net/srmquo4s/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the button position manually to 0

```
 "buttonPosition": {
                x: 0
        },
```

here is the full and formatted fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pm30yuum/2/